# hide/show fab with scale animation

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm using custom floatingactionmenu. I need to implement scale animation on show/hide menu button like here
[floating action button behaviour](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsZU1kZWhRYWZpUDg/components-buttons-fab-behavior_01_xhdpi_012.mp4)

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Use the fab.show() and fab.hide() methods provided by the design lib. Also you might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937028/how-to-animate-floatingactionbutton-like-in-google-app-for-android)

Comment: its not android fab library its custom fab menu [here](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

Comment: Why do you want to use a library when the framework provides this control for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953215/1318946

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use these scale animations for fab button, it gives same effect like design lib fab button.

**scale_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="85%"
        android:pivotY="85%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

**scale_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="85%"
        android:pivotY="85%"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Where do i put this, how do i apply it?

Comment: Like Anuj said: 
`FloatingActionButton fab = this.findViewById( ... );
Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.scale_up);
fab.startAnimation(myAnim);`

Answer (score 82):

The design support library revision 22.2.1  added the hide() and show() methods to the `FloatingActionButton` class, so you can use these from now on.

```
FloatingActionButton mFab;
mFab.hide();
mFab.show();
```

You can apply your own animation on it.
For more info [check this.](https://evgenii.com/blog/spring-button-animation-on-android/)
And for more information about FAB, check the [official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

Comment: linking google's stuff is ridiculous, we need example

Answer (score 8):

Load these animation on your custom view. Don't forget to set pivot point to 50% and interpolator to linear interpolator.

**scale_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

**scale_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" />
</set>
```