# FloatingActionButton on scroll down hidden effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-scrollview, floating-action-button

I am trying to make `floatingActionButton` hide when scroll down and showing again when scroll up, I used `setOnScrollChangeListener` for ScrollView to doing that

**the XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="start|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8_share_480"
        />
```

**code**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (scrollY < 0) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
} else {
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int mScrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
            if (mScrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (mScrollY < 0) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[the result](https://i.imgur.com/vIWURB8.gifv).

 It seems working but there are two problems sometimes when scroll the fab up does not appear, second it disappears directly without any effects the more clarify in this GIF [Destination](https://i.imgur.com/3qYs32W.gifv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @JEFF, after monitoring the `OnScrollChangeListener`, I changed the value in condition to 
 `scrollY < 22` and it's appearing again. 
regarding the second issue I searching for How to doing animation and I found there are two ways to doing that

**first** is to using `fab.hide` and  `fab.show` instead of method `setVisibility();`

the code after edit

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {
        //   Log.d("ScrollView","scrollX_"+scrollX+"_scrollY_"+scrollY+"_oldScrollX_"+oldScrollX+"_oldScrollY_"+oldScrollY);
        if (scrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
            fab.hide();
        } else if (scrollY < 22) {
            fab.show();

        }
    });
} else {
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
        int mScrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
        if (mScrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
            fab.hide();
        } else if (mScrollY < 22) {
            fab.show();
        }
    });
}
```

**second way** is using custom scale animations for scall up, down, like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554065/4205927)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because after you scroll to bottom from top it's true it will be hidden but it cannot know when you scroll to top because your `mScrollY < 0` in the position is not truly less than 0. try using the code from this, it can give the position of old position and new then you can compare it so it will know when you starting scroll to top or bottom

This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230992/10396176

Comment: Thank you for clarifications, part of the problem has been solved. remain hidden effect of the fab.
<br/> If you have knowledge of this, please let me know

Comment: which problems remain?

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the same by using the following in my FAB xml. Nothing else required:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fbListFood = findViewById(R.id.fbListFood);
scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY > 0 && fbListFood.isShown()) {
                fbListFood.hide();
            } else if (scrollY < 22) {
                fbListFood.show();

            }
        }
    });
} else {
    

    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int mScrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
            if (mScrollY > 0 && fbListFood.isShown()) {
                fbListFood.hide();
            } else if (mScrollY < 22) {
                fbListFood.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```